# While developing a Chat application using WinForms in Visual Studio, getting errors (An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, client-server

While developing a windows Chat Application using C# and WinForms in Visual Studio. Since I am beginner in Programming and Client Server communications, I coded simultaneously by watching YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDVfpPq3weo.

Application ran successfully but,

Before entering the chat in the application  I inserted my IP Address in both applications as per the YouTube Video and entered the Port number as (81-mine, 80-friends) and vice versa in second application.

**After hitting Connect button for entering conversation, it throw's an error stating**

> See the end of this message for details on invoking
> just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)
   at WinChat.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Desktop\WinChat\Form1.cs:line 80
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
```

**My code below for your reference**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace WinChat
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Socket sck;
        EndPoint epLocal, epRemote;
        byte[] buffer; 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       

        private void groupBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txt_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // 1. Setting up a socket
            sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

            // 2. Get User IP
            TextLocalIP.Text = GetlocalIP();
            TextRemoteIP.Text = GetlocalIP();

           
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // 4. Binding socket or Connecting with IP addresses 
            epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(TextLocalIP.Text), Convert.ToInt32(TextLocalPort.Text));
            sck.Bind(epLocal);


            // Getting remote IP
            epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(TextRemoteIP.Text), Convert.ToInt32(TextRemoteIP.Text));
            // Connecting with Remote IP
            sck.Connect(epRemote);
            // Listening with specific port
            buffer = new byte[1500];
            //                                                                                             This below function is positioned at the bottom of functions
            sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
        }

        private string GetlocalIP()
        {
            IPHostEntry host;
            host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach(IPAddress ip in host.AddressList){
                if(ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    return ip.ToString();

                }
            }
            return "**(MY IP)**";
            
        }

        private void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // First for sending the message we need to convert String to byte 
            ASCIIEncoding aEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] sendingMessage = new byte[1500];
            sendingMessage = aEncoding.GetBytes(TextMessage.Text);


            //Sending the encoded message to friend
            sck.Send(sendingMessage);

            //Add message to the List Box 
            ListMessage.Items.Add("Me: " + TextMessage.Text);

            // Refresshing Text Message Box
            TextMessage.Text = "";
        }


        // Link to new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack) == MessageCallBack function is given below:
        private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult aResult)
        {
            try
            {
                // Declaring Byte Array for receiving Data 
                byte[] receivedData = new byte[1500];
                receivedData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;

                // Converting Byte to string 
                ASCIIEncoding aEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                string receivedMessage = aEncoding.GetString(receivedData);

                // Adding this message into list Box
                ListMessage.Items.Add("Friend:" + receivedMessage);
                buffer = new byte[1500];
                sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: In function:  private string GetlocalIP()
-> I have used my IP address but haven't mentioned here..

Please guide me

Comment: The error message tells you the exact place in your code (*WinChat.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Desktop\WinChat\Form1.cs:line 80*) where the problem occurs. So, please don't post tons of code and links to images and videos. Simply showing us the method `button1_Click` with a comment on line 80 (like `// <===`) together with an explanation of the problem would be enough.

Comment: ok understood.. Thank you

Comment: You should look at `int.TryParse`, it doesn't throw an exception with an incorrect format (and users making typos is hardly _exceptional_. I understand why you blacked out your IP address, but you should really show what format you have in that field (_an_ IP address, just not _your_ IP address)

Answer (score 2):

> Convert.ToInt32(TextRemoteIP.Text)

You are using `TextRemoteIP.Text` in place of both the IP and port number.

Shouldn't it be the port number instead?